# Duplicated mapping key in serverless.yml

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm using **Serverless** to deploy a couple of functions written in C# to AWS.

While deploying a message **duplicated mapping key in "...\serverless.yml"** is thrown.

[image]

Separately, both functions get deployed but when put together the said error message is shown.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried deleting the .serveless directory and redeploying?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "service": "serverlessquick",
  "provider": {
    "name": "aws",
    "runtime": "nodejs4.3"
  },
  "functions": {
    "hello": {
      "handler": "handler.hello",
      "events": [
        {
          "http": {
            "path": "hello",
            "method": "get"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Make your yaml code into json this way any mistakes are obvious, and will be more likely to be picked up by the parser. If anyone comes across this, use the referenced config above.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error but in my case it was indentation problem. Go through your YML file and see if the changes you have made have the correct identation. A json parser as mention by others can help narrow down where in the YML file the problem exists